# What is the purpose of creating an object of a class in the same class?

Tags: java

Please consider the following code.. Why the object of class Test is created in the same class Test? Is there any difference in the objects ob1 and ob2?

```
class Test {
  int a;

  Test(int i) {
    a = i;
  }

  Test incrByTen() {
    Test temp = new Test(a+10);
    return temp;
  }
}

class RetOb {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Test ob1 = new Test(2);
    Test ob2;

    ob2 = ob1.incrByTen();
    System.out.println("ob1.a: " + ob1.a);
    System.out.println("ob2.a: " + ob2.a);

    ob2 = ob2.incrByTen();
    System.out.println("ob2.a after second increase: "
                        + ob2.a);
  }
}
```

Comment: Look at src code of ValuedEnum implementation of Apache (Commons?), It is a good example when it makes sense.

Comment: What is the output after running this? It should give you the clues to the answer. If you're still stuck try changing incrByTen to not create a new object and see what the output is then.

Comment: This is actually a start to make the Test instances immutable. Now, if only int was `final`.

Comment: It's not uncommon for a class to have methods that create new objects of the class.  The `String` class does this all the time.  If `s` is a `String`, there are many methods that you could call on `s` that will create a _new_ `String` object.  Like `s.substring(...)`.

Comment: Instances of class `Test` are **immutable**, which is often a very good thing. It means that once you've created a `Test` object its value will never change, so you can pass it around and share it between different threads without worrying that other code will change it (mutate it) behind your back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously there's a difference: Their data member has a different value. In other words, while these objects are of the same class, **they are in a different state**.

Could `incrByTen` work increase the value of the same object instead of creating a new one? **Absolutely.**

Then why bother returning a new object? It could be one of the following reasons:

- Perhaps it simply makes sense in the context of the method. For example, if a method is called `makeACopy`, you'd expect it to create a new object of the same class, not return the original.
- Another reason is if the objects of this class are **intended to be immutable**. Objects are immutable if **their state cannot change after their creation**. In this case, any operation to such an object wouldn't modify the original object, but it would create a modified one from the original. One great example of this is the `String` class - appending strings or replacing sequences in a string does not change the original, but it creates new strings instead.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but I didn't get your first reason.. :/

Comment: @user3284881 If you had a (hypothetical) method called `makeACopy`, would you assume (judging from its name) that the expression `a.makeACopy()` it returns a new object or the current one (the object `a`)? I think you'd expect a *new* object (even if it's a copy). Well, for that method to be able to give you a copy, internally it would be creating a new object of the same class!

Comment: So it means, this type of method, which returns an object in this case, is used to create a copy of an object?

Comment: @user3284881 It is one possible reason to create an object, but it's definitely not the only one. The second reason I gave in my answer is also a valid (and very common) reason why some methods create a new object of the same class.